# React renders blank page for non default routes in build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {console.log("Loading Routes")}

        <Route path="/booking" component={Booking} />
        <Route path="/bookings" component={Bookings} />
        <Route path="/admin/login" component={AdminLogin} />
        <Route path="/admin/panel" component={AdminPanel} />
        <Route path="/admin/new" component={AddPhone} />
        <Route path="/admin/list" component={PhoneList} />
        <Route path="/admin/edit/:id" component={EditPhone} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

```
app.use(express.static("./client/build"));

// Routes for the Application

app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/api"));
app.use("/api/booking", require("./routes/booking"));

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  console.log(1);
  res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build/index.html"));
});

app.get("/*/*", (req, res) => {
  console.log(1);
  res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Listening to PORT : ", PORT);
});
```

I am using the above code to serve it, everything runs fine on build, but when I serve the files with my server, the default / route runs perfectly but the /admin/login route or any other route loads a blank page.

Answer (score -1):

Does the root of your server includes .htaccess file ?

If not create .htaccess file and this inside:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```